# libsnd file on hpc cluster

Tags: c++, compilation, libsndfile, environment-modules

I have requested that we have libsnd file installed on the hpc cluster. The admin said that I can test this via the following link:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erikd/libsndfile/master/examples/sndfile-to-text.c

```
$ module load libsndfile/1.0.28 $ 
$ gcc -1/gpfs/apps/sw/libsndfile-1.0.28/include -L gpfs/apps/sw/libsndfile-1.0.28/lib, -lsndfile test.c 
$ ./a.out
```

However I am not sure how to this yet!! I have a program file.cpp that uses:

```
#include <sndfile.hh>
```

I tried the following:

```
module load -l/gpfs1/apps/sw/libsndfile-1.0.28/include -L/gpfs1/apps/sw/libsndfile-1.0.28/lib -lsndfile file.cpp
```

but got the following error:

```
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'g'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '1'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'w'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'b'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'n'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'd'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'e'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '-'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '1'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '.'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '0'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '.'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '2'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '8'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'n'
cmdUlvl.c(206):ERROR:46: Undefined userlevel 'de'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'L'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'g'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '1'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'w'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'b'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'n'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'd'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'e'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '-'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '1'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '.'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '0'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '.'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '2'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '8'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option '/'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'b'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'n'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'd'
getopt.c(1087):ERROR:45: Invalid option 'e'
ModuleCmd_Load.c(204):ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'spectro.cpp'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `module` commands helps to define environment variables. It cannot compile a program, so the `module load` command you ran ends in error as `module` does not understand your request.

The `libsndfile/1.0.28` modulefile should define useful variables for compilation, like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You can check what environment variable the modulefile defines with:

```
$ module display libsndfile/1.0.28
```

If the `libsndfile/1.0.28` modulefile defines environment variables to simplify compilation setup (by defining include path and library path), you may just need to type:

```
$ module load 
$ gcc -lsndfile test.c 
$ ./a.out
```